# Multiply percantage values

Tags: java, double, percentage

I need to multiply a `double` value by `12%`, how can I do so?

```
public class AnnualMaintenanceFee {

  public void GetTotal(int TotalND) {
    double software=1500;
    double TNDWithSof= 1500+TotalND;
    double AMF= TNDWithSof 12;
    System.out.println("New Total: "+AMF);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `double AMF= TNDWithSof 12;` mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this,

```
double AMF= TNDWithSof * 0.12; // 0.12 means 12/100(12%), you can use 0.12 directly
System.out.println("New Total: "+AMF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
(yourDouble * 12) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` in `12%` is no more than an *operator* that divides by 100 (or equivalently from a mathematical perspective, multiplies by 0.01).

So `12%` can be written as `12 * 0.01`. I prefer that to writing `12 / 100` since the latter, unless you're careful, will be performed in *integer division* with any fractional part being discarded.

Do consider using a currency type though for money values: floating point numbers are not designed to represent exact money amounts.

Answer (score 0):

For multiplication use `*`, for percent `12%` you can use `12/100` like:

```
double AMF= TNDWithSof*(12/100);
System.out.println("New Total: "+AMF);
```

Because the division`(12/100)` be evaluated in first because it's inside bracket, and finally evaluate `TNDWithSof*0.12`.